# A better way to update/Import projects

Tags: acumatica

Just a general question, I've been doing all my customization on my own local instance of acumatica, then I import my new project into the live application, and publish it while unpublishing the outdated project. Is there a better approach to this, like a git version control of updating the project, or is importing a new project every time you make alterations to the local that you want to push to live the only way? I'm trying to avoid having hundreds of projects imported over time. I do have my live application on Bitbucket, but that doesn't alleviate the problem of going from local project-> live project.

Any recommendations are welcome, Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store a single deployment package for each customization project in a version control system, for example, Git repository.
However it is just a file. To update the content of the customization project in the database of the live application, you have to **IMPORT** the data from this file. To apply the altered customization, you should **PUBLISH** the project.

Comment: I figured what you've mentioned was the best approach. Thanks again!